# Почему при преобразовании элементов массива через parseInt некоторые элементы равны NaN

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задание было из числа сделать перевернутый массив. Как оно работает не могу понять в данном варианте именно с parseInt, почему некоторые элементы равны NaN

```
array.toString().split('').reverse().map(parseInt)
```

Comment: Так вы код покажите, покажите, за каких условий у вас ошибка возникает. Что у вас в дебаге?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в таком виде вторым аргументом в `parseInt` передается индекс элемента, при значениях меньше 2х и больше 36 - будет возвращаться `NaN`, а также если в строке есть цифры **больше** чем значение индекса

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое, поняла логику

Comment: @Евгения в дубликате описан принцип работы функций переводящих из строки в число